# Itext list duplicate id = 1 android

Tags: java, android, itext

Where is error?
When I generate pdf then repeats itself and is id = 1 then id = 1 and only id = 2 and so on.

```
List list = new List(List.ORDERED);
String query = "SELECT * FROM property ";
Cursor c1 = db.selectQuery(query);
if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
    if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            list.add(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("id")));
            list.add(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("type")));
            list.add(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("address")));
            list.add(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("value")));
            list.add(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("debt")));
            list.add(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("notes")));
            doc.add(list);
        }while (c1.moveToNext());
    }
 }
 c1.close();
```

Comment: Do the other fields repeat as well, or just the 'id'?

Comment: hmmm yet another question why i put the same object in the loop ... maybe because you do not create the new object inside the loop ...

Comment: Others fields too repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the list at every cycle.

Try putting `doc.add(list);` after  `c1.close();` instead.